# can I pass any parameter to a task through browser when we are scheduling any task in WSO2 ESB?

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I found that I can define some properties that can be injected into a `sequence`. But in my case, I want to know if it is possible or not passing parameters to the `ESB Task` in the browser when we are scheduling an `ESB Task` in  **WSO2 Enterprise Integrator**.

I'm trying to do some analysis on some data over a period of 3 months on a day-to-day basis, So right now I'm manually changing the date in the query to fetch the data from the database for analysis and then redeploying the application again. It is taking too much time. So if it's possible this will save a lot of time and effort.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a message that can be injected to a proxy or a sequence in a task. You can develop a custom task as well. Please refer to the documentation and if it does not meet your requirement please elaborate more on this.

[1]-https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI611/Adding+and+Scheduling+Tasks
[2]-https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Writing+Tasks+Sample

Answer (score -1):

1. You can pass as many parameters as you like in POST request
2. May be useful to know about transfer option message with Content-Type = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" or HTML in POST request

Comment: I'm not trying to pass parameters to a post request